# How to set default openlayers marker/pin position in a django form for create case

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, openlayers

I am trying to do something seemingly simple yet difficult in the details.  I have a django form with an embedded OL2 map with 2 display cases: 1) new (create) and 2) already existing.  In the existing form case, I have a lat/long and this gets correctly passed to my *OsmMapPointWidget*, as expected and the map is centered over that point with a draggable marker shown.  So far, all good.  Now, let's take the *new* form case AND assume that I can want to incorporate the user's current lat/long (gathered from the browser via *navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()* (which by the way is a deferred callback)).  It seems there are numerous problems:

1. The django widget does not have the user's location available because that becomes available after form rendering (i.e., in the browser itself) so there is no lat/long yet available.
2. By the time the user's current location is known, the map is (presumably drawn, centered and has a marker on it), so django can have no part in this process - it all has to be done in js after the map is up and running (see the part abut deferred location callback).

Now, through a lot of sleight of hand I have been able to get the map centered over the user's current location by using the location in the location callback and doing essentially:

```
map.setCenter(users_location).
```

However, while this gets the map centered correctly I have two remaining issues:

1. The OpenLayers MapWidget has already drawn a marker at (0,0) (since the form is new).
2. I can't figure out how to move that already drawn marker to the desired lat/long.  I have code to create a *new* marker, etc. and I can get that placed but it's worthless because the "real" marker is still sitting at 0,0 (W of Africa).

So, how to I get find of the OpenLayers marker and move it to where I need it.  Effectively, I want:

```
setExistingDraggableMarkerLocation( some_position );
```

BTW, I am somewhat new to OL so maybe "marker" is not the correct term?  It's the default small draggable yellow circle.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Django users OpenLayers 2 for the default map widgets. Are you confusing OpenLayers 2 with OpenLayers 3, or are you using some other, non Django-contrib, widgets?

Comment: I stand corrected - it is openlayers 2.13.1.  I am using floppyforms but that doesn't matter for this discussion.  I will fix my post above.

Comment: One possible way to do this may be to defer the instantiation of the map until after the location callback occurs (i.e., have the callback itself instantiate the map widget).  One issue with that is that the location callback can take an indefinite about of time (although you can set a timeout).